# SQL Server: sys.master_files vs. sys.database_files

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

What is the difference of the sys.master_files and sys.database_files? I have about 20 databases in my instance but when I query the sys.master_files I do not receive any rows. Why? When I query sys.database_files I get the information about the database files concerning the current database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[sys.master_files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782(v=SQL.100).aspx) :

> Contains a row per file of a database
> as stored in the master database. This
> is a single, system-wide view.

[sys.database_files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397.aspx) :

> Contains a row per file of a database as stored in the database itself. This is a per-database view.

So, `SELECT * FROM sys.master_files` should list the files for each database in the instance whereas `SELECT * FROM sys.database_files` should list the files for the specific database context.

Testing this here (SQL 2K8), it works as per the above?

**Update:**
If you're not seeing rows from sys.master_files, it could be a permissions issue as BOL states:

> The minimum permissions that are
> required to see the corresponding row
> are CREATE DATABASE, ALTER ANY
> DATABASE, or VIEW ANY DEFINITION.

Whereas for sys.database_files just requires membership in the public role.

Comment: Thanks. I'm puzzled because select * from sys.master_files does not produce any rows. Our database and log files are located on different logical devices on HP EVA. Would that be the reason (I'm not a DBA)?

Comment: @juur - see the update in my answer - could be a permissions problem