# Using subquery in SSIS results in NULL values

Tags: database-permissions

I am trying to execute some SQL within a OLE DB Source Connector within SSIS that will get some statistics regarding databasesizes.

This query ran fine when used in SSIS for one server. Now however I am looping through a number of servers and two columns that should be (and had been) producing ints now produce NULLS with datatype four-byte signed integer [DT_I4].
These are DataFileSizeMB and LogFileSizeMB.
I am at a total loss here... (as always when turning here, it kinda feels like defeat simply having to ask ;)

This is the query, why won't it run in SSIS and does it run in SSMS?

```
   SELECT       @@SERVERNAME as Server
                ,getdate() as Meetmoment
                ,name as Databasenaam
                ,(  SELECT CAST(ROUND(SUM(size), 0) AS float) AS Expr1
                    FROM  ( SELECT database_id, type, size * 8.0 / 1024 AS size  
                            FROM sys.master_files) AS fs_2
                    WHERE        (type = 0) AND (database_id = db.database_id)
                ) AS DataFileSizeMB
                ,(  SELECT CAST(ROUND(SUM(size), 0) AS float) AS Expr1
                    FROM (  SELECT database_id, type, size * 8.0 / 1024 AS size
                            FROM sys.master_files) AS fs_1
                     WHERE        (type = 1) AND (database_id = db.database_id)
                ) AS LogFileSizeMB
 FROM            sys.databases AS db
 ORDER BY DataFileSizeMB DESC
```

I changed the query to

```
select @@SERVERNAME as Server, 
            getdate() as Meetmoment, 
            mdf.name as Databasename, 
            mdf.Size_MBs as  DataFileSizeMB, 
            ldf.Size_MBs as LogFileSizeMB 
FROM 

(SELECT d.name,
ROUND(SUM(mf.size) * 8 / 1024, 0) Size_MBs
FROM sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = mf.database_id
where type = 0
GROUP BY d.name) as mdf 

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT d.name,
ROUND(SUM(mf.size) * 8 / 1024, 0) Size_MBs
FROM sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = mf.database_id
where type = 1
GROUP BY d.name) as ldf on mdf.name = ldf.name
```

but alas...... It must be something else............ Where to look?

As far as I can see these columns are ints all the way, except during calculation. I tried changing all relevant columns, in- and outputs to float but no difference.
Already in Query Builder the outcome fopr these columns is NULL where in SSMS the query runs just fine

Comment: Which column in your query is now returning a `NULL`? You state you're iterating through a server list, which server are you connected to when the query generates a NULL? My assumption is that you are running into a permissions issue on the connection with the NULL.

Comment: It are both number columns. It also goes wrong on the server it worked originally

Comment: @billinkc U were completely right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My assumption is that you are running into a permissions issue on the connection with the NULL. –  @billinkc 18 hours ago*

Well, bugger..... That is actually it.... Turns out the account I used DOES have access to `SYS.DATABASES` but **NOT** to `SYS.master_files`.....

I have something to look into ;)

See the following threads

- [How to give a user access to sys.master_files in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911953/how-to-give-a-user-access-to-sys-master-files-in-sql-server)
- [SQL Server: sys.master_files vs. sys.database_files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174520/sql-server-sys-master-files-vs-sys-database-files)

I ended up creating a script that creates a job that creates a table that inserts the relevant columns from sys.master_files in a table on which the reporting user has db_datareader. It is that table I use in the query used in SYS

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the query and avoided all subqueries: this one did the trick:

```
select     @@SERVERNAME as Server, 
            getdate() as Meetmoment, 
            sysdb.name as Databasename, 
            sum(datafile.Size* 8 / 1024) as  DataFileSizeMB, 
            sum(logfile.Size* 8 / 1024) as LogFileSizeMB 
FROM SYS.DATABASES (NOLOCK) sysdb 
        left join SYS.master_files datafile on sysdb.database_id = datafile.database_id and datafile.type = 0
        left join SYS.master_files logfile on sysdb.database_id = logfile.database_id and logfile.type = 1
group by sysdb.name
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it ran only in the query builder, after executing the package I get NULLS again...... It has to have to do anything with the destination column.....